# Правильно ли расставлены знаки? В первом случае - точки после кавычек, а во втором - запятая

Tags: грамматика

1) Нашёл хозяина заведения: «Мне недорогую комнату». – «Пять долларов». – «А за четыре?» – «Можно и за четыре, душ холодный».

2) «Как Фрейду – нудистский пляж, Андрею Рублеву – Манеж, инвалидной коляске – гараж, и мышеловке – мышь...», – представлялось мне то, что ждёт впереди.

Comment: Грамматика, говорите?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2):

1) Точка **всегда** за кавычками (в русском);

2) отточие ("многоточие") отменяет запятую.

> «У Гёте где-то сказано, что на чужом языке нельзя создать ничего
>   значительного, - я же всегда считала, что это неверно...» - писала М.
>   Цветаева в 1926 г. Рильке.

См.: [Знаки препинания при прямой речи и цитатах.](http://www.hi-edu.ru/e-books/xbook142/01/part-031.htm)

---

[Знаки препинания при диалоге](http://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827535.html)

§ 51.2

> Если реплики следуют в подбор без указания, кому они принадлежат, то
>   каждая из них заключается в кавычки и отделяется от соседней тире: 
>   *«Так ты женат? Не знал я ране! Давно ли?» — «Около двух лет». — «На ком?» — «На Лариной». — «Татьяне?» — «Ты ей знаком?» — «Я им сосед»*
>   (П.).

Comment: Спасибо. А после слов «А за четыре?», точка не нужна?

Comment: Не-а. ))) Щас правило поищу.

Comment: Ога, есть. В ответ добавила, со ссылкою.